# C++ Find node with highest value in unordered tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I tried searching for this problem on stackoverflow but couldn't find it, so pardon me if it already existed.

So, what I wish to do is to create a function that traverses a tree and returns a pointer to the Node with the highest value. The Tree would be unordered and asymmetric, and will not have a fixed depth. Each node has a pointer to its Parent node, a list containing its Child nodes, and an integer named 'value'. And the tree would have a pointer to its root node, like this:

```
struct Node
{
private:
    Node* parent;
    list<Node> childs;
    int value;
public:
    // Getters, setters and constructors
}

struct Tree
{
private:
    Node* root;
public:
    // Getters, setters and constructors
}
```

And, as I stated before, I wish to make a function that traverses the entire tree, aka every single Node in the entire tree regardless of the depth, and returns a pointer to the node with the highest value. I assume it'll require recursion, but I can't figure out a way to do this.

Pardon me if my question seems dumb / stupid, but I really need help

Comment: Look at depth-first and breadth-first graph traversal.

Comment: The idea here would be to implement a `Tree::iterator` type that allows iterating through a `Tree`'s `Node`s, and then using the power of `<algorithm>` on this (and other) problems. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursive method, which returns the pointer to the node with maximal value of current and child nodes:

```
struct Node
{
...
  Node* getMaxNode()
  {
    Node* maxNode = this;
    for (auto& child : this->childs) {
      Node* childsMaxNode = child.getMaxNode();
      if (childsMaxNode->getValue() > maxNode->getValue())
        maxNode = childsMaxNode;
    }
    return maxNode;
  }
}
```

If current node doesn't have child nodes, it will return pointer to the current node. So, in `struct Tree` you can implement something like this:

```
struct Tree
{
  Node* getMax()
  {
    return this->root->getMaxNode();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed